# How to reduce left margin in this Sharelatex (Professional CV) template?

Tags: spacing, margins, sharelatex, cv

I have been trying to reduce the space in the left and right margins of this template? The initial image is

[image: Initial]

So, I added

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=-20mm,top=26mm,right=-26mm,bottom=-20mm]{geometry}
```

in the preamble. However, the result is not as I expected (the horizontal lines go to the far right end, while the left margin space stays intact). I would like the left margin space to nullify as well. How can I go about this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}        
%%%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
    {\Huge Alessandro \textsc{Plasmati}
}\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Someplace, Italy  | dd Month 1912 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & CV Inn 19, 20301, Milano, Italy \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & +39 123 456789\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}            
{alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and not just a code snippet so that we can reproduce the problem on our end? [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Troy I have just added a minimal working example. I am not able to understand how to get the "Personal Data" (and further sections) start from the extreme left.

Comment: I'd recommend you have a look at documentation of the [`layaureo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/layaureo) package that you use, and consider if you really require it. I'd reckon that it's responsible for the extra 'binding' space on the left that you are looking to avoid.